# How do I create an immutable static public object within a class?

Tags: c++

I have a class Color that holds values for the red, green, blue, and alpha channels of a color. The class constructor lets you create a new color by specifying values for the four channels. However, for convenience, I would also like to have some "premade" colors available for the programmer. For example instead of having something like

`DrawBox(new Color(255, 0, 0));`

you would be able to say

`DrawRectangle(Color::Red);`

Where Color.Red is an instance of Color that lives inside the Color class. How can I declare these instances of Color inside the Color class? I'm sure there's a name for this technique, but I had no idea what search terms to use when I was looking for help online.

I'm not using any built-in or publicly-available classes or libraries because this is part of a personal exercise in creating a basic graphics stack.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Aside: your two examples are not equivalent. The first passes a *pointer* to DrawBox(), while the second presumably passes on object.

Comment: @Benjin The name you are looking for is an `enum`. C++ only supports integer enums natively, but there are ways to get similar results (see answers). Other languages, such as Java for instance, support enums of any type.

Comment: @Coincoin: He wants a full-fledge class, with certain predefined colors. With `enum` you cannot do that. `enums` are more like labels with integral values, and often you don't care about the values themselves, but labels are all you want.

Comment: @Robᵩ, thanks for spotting that.  Pointers would probably be ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, avoid using `new`. You could use `Color` as simple value-type.

Now as an answer to your question, yes, you can do that as:

```
//color.h

typedef unsigned char byte;

class Color
{
    public:
        //declaration
        const static Color Red;
        const static Color Green;
        const static Color Blue;
    public:

       Color(byte red, byte green, byte blue);
};

//define the static members in color.cpp file
#include "color.h"

const Color Color::Red(255,0,0);
const Color Color::Green(0,255,0);
const Color Color::Blue(0,0,255);
```

Then use `Color::Red` as you want to use.

Comment: Does `Red` need to be defined as well?

Comment: @K-ballo: The current compiler doens't support it, there is no point in it. I changed my code to C++03.

Comment: But has there been a change in this respect in _C++11_? Have the rules for _static const integrals_ been generalized?

Comment: @K-ballo: You can initialize them in the class itself, though I'm not sure if they still need definition outside the class. :|

Comment: On the original version: A static data member initializer inside the class definition must satisfy the requirements for a constant expression.  A definition outside the class with no initializer is required.

Comment: @Nawaz: It seems it has been extended per _[9.4.2]/3_, `constexpr` static members initialized by a _constant expression_ do not necessarily need a definition if not _odr-used_

Comment: Unfortunately, it's harder to not odr-use an object of literal class type, than to not odr-use an object of integer type.